# How to change a cefpython window icon?

Tags: python, icons, chromium-embedded, roblox

Currently i am working with `cefpython3`. and i made a roblox embed but my code seems to not be showing the icon on the top left corner like any other windows application. I also get a message from `cef` and the message goes something like `Invalid argument: icon`.

My code:

```
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import sys
import win32gui,win32con


def open(url):
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook
    cef.Initialize()
    cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=url,window_title='Roblox',icon='Rbx_icon.ico')
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
    cef.MessageLoop()
    
try:
    open('https://web.roblox.com/home')
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```